# Give everyone glowing after they throw an item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

With command blocks, how do I make it so when someone throws a stone hoe called **Glow**
It gives everyone in a radius of 200 blocks a glowing effect?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are required to check if the stone hoe is thrown.

Legacy (1.12 or below) (You need to run two commands, all in Repeating Command Blocks and Always Active!

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=item] add glow {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Glow"}}}}

testfor @e[type=item,tag=glow]
```

1.13 (Repeating Command Block, Always active):

```
execute if entity @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Glow\"}"}}}}]
```

Then, after it's triggered (via a comparator or command chain), run the following command to give everyone in a 200 block radius the glowing effect. (Not clear! Time? Level?)

Legacy:

```
execute @e[tag=glow] ~ ~ ~ effect @a[r=200] glowing <time?> <level?>
```

1.13:

```
execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Glow"}}}}] at @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Glow"}}}}] run effect give @a[distance=..200] glowing <time?> <level?>
```

After that, if expected, you can remove the Glow stone hoe.

Legacy:

```
kill @e[tag=glow]
```

1.13:

```
kill @e[nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Glow"}}}}]
```

If you felt that this answer has no "whys" included in it, feel free to post a comment about this.